# Code deduplication in rust for similar structs

Tags: rust

I have a small projects where there are a few similar structs where the implementation of `Ord` and `PartialOrd` is the same.  I am new to rust from (primarily) dynamic languages where code duplication is often considered an anti-pattern and I'm wondering if there is there a way to avoid duplicating this code?   Or, more generally, is that something I should worry about in rust?

For example:

```rust
struct Event {
  start: i32,
  end: i32,
  . . .
}

impl Ord for Event {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        let cmp = self.start.cmp(&other.start);
        if cmp == Ordering::Equal {
            (self.end - self.start).cmp(&(other.end - other.start))
        } else {
            cmp
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Event {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> { Some(self.cmp(&other)) }
}

struct Reservation {
    start: i32.
    end: i32,
    . . . 
}

impl Ord for Reservation {
    // same implementation as Event
}

impl PartialOrd for Reservation {
    // same implementation as Event
}
```

Is there a way to have `Reservation` and `Event` share the implementation of `cmp` so that code does not need to be duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of your problem is that you are first and foremost duplicating the same fields on both structs. This can easily be avoided by factoring them out into some separate structure, e.g.:

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
struct TimeRange {
    start: i32,
    end: i32,
}
```

Then you can implement `Ord` & `PartialOrd` for it once.

```rust
impl Ord for TimeRange {
    // ...
}

impl PartialOrd for TimeRange {
    // ...
}
```

Since `TimeRange` is now `Ord`, you can simply derive the `Ord` trait for `Event` and `Reservation` since that will delegate to `TimeRange`'s impl.

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]
struct Event {
    range: TimeRange,
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]
struct Reservation {
    range: TimeRange,
}
```

Besides, in your specific example you seem to sort by `start` first, then by duration. But if `start`-s are equal, then comparing by duration is equivalent to comparing by `end` and thus you are effectively sorting by `start` then `end`, which the default derived `Ord` would give you without needing to write nay code.

Comment: Does it work with additional attributes in `Reservation` and `Event` that should not contribute to the ordering?

Comment: Not with the `derive` attributes, no. There is no way to derive `Ord` using only a subset of fields. But at least you will be able to call `self.range.cmp()` from e.g. `Event`-s implementation.

Comment: Thanks to @CoronA . that clarification (about there being additional attributes) would be great to add to the answer if you have the time.